# Minimal GIMP install to work from command line

Tags: installation, command-line-interface, ubuntu

Ubuntu Jaunty (9.04) Server

I need to do some server-side image scripting that [apparently only GIMP is able to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168614/how-to-create-a-layered-psd-file-from-command-line).

I'd hate to install X Window and GTK only for that.

Is there a way to ***install* GIMP without all that bloat**, so it may work from command-line only?

(A silly question, I know, but perhaps there is a hope?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between installing an actual X server, and just the libraries involved (libgtk, Xlib, etc.). I have tried to compile GIMP, and while I can do it without an X server installed, I do still need libgtk, Xlib, and all that installed for it to compile, despite playing with several `./configure` flags. `./configure` does not recognise flags such as `--without-gegl` or `--without-x11`.

I have come to the conclusion that the answer to this question is that it is not possible. However, I don't think it's as bad as it sounds. Chances are you already have a server application running that uses GLib or something.

Comment: Thanks. I'm probably fine with *installing* X server as long as I do not have to actually *run* it... I admit I'm a bit unsure on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

[**GIMP Batch Mode**](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/)

---

The install steps here for [the Hardy Ubuntu are on command line](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-gimp-261-on-ubuntu-804-hardy-heron.html).
However, I am not quite sure you can get by without a GTK install... 
Is that necessary?

Actually, there seems to be a `nogtk` install option. Have not tried it.

<sub>As an extreme alternative, have you considered the portable gimp on a flash drive

maybe used from a separate windows installation for the purpose?</sub>

Comment: I know that it is possible to run and control Gimp from command-line. But is it possible to **install** it without X Window and GTK?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to avoid installing X Window and GTK on my server.

Comment: Also: what do you mean by "a separate Windows installation"?

Comment: But a 'separate Windows installation', i meant you could copy the data across to another windows system where you could even use a portable GIMP edition to work. You have the install on your flash drive and none on either of the machines. I don't think you can have a flash installation of GIMP usable in Linux easily (that is the reason for the separate Windows reference).

Answer (score -1):

It's not quite what you asked but have you looked into [ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It has always been my solution of choice for command-line editing of image (specially for batch processing).

[Here is the reference for installing it in ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ImageMagick)

Comment: If you read the supplied link, you can see he's already tried ImageMagik.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that ImageMagick can'd do what I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168614/how-to-create-a-layered-psd-file-from-command-line